# What if function has cartesian product as domain but actual function only uses one variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, elementary-set-theory

If a function's domain is $ℤ \times ℤ$ and codomain is $ℤ$ but the actual function only uses one variable, is it a valid function?

eg.

$f(x) = x + 3$

Can I just put an integer $x$ value in, which will provide a value, even if $y$ is not used in the function itself?

Comment: Anything is a function as long as every input corresponds to a unique output. In this case what you mean should technically be written as $f(x,y)=x+3$ or more pedantically $f((x,y))=x+3$, and indeed every $(x,y)$ maps to the unique output $x+3$, so it is a function.

Comment: "is it a valid function?"  Yes. "even if Y is not used in the function itself?" Yes. Function takes an input and maps it to output but there is no stipulation that the function 'thinks" about the input in any way.  Consider constant function $f(x) = 7$.  Period.  Everything gets mapped to $7$ and the what the input actually *is* doesn't matter. It goes the $7$ no matter what.  that's a fine function. Likewise take the function $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is positive an $f(x)=0$ is negative. the *value* of $x$ is completely ignore and only its sign is consider. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3):

If the domain of $f$ in your example is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(x)=x+3$ does not make sense, since $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $3$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ (how can you add an element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to an element of $\mathbb{Z}$?).

However, if you mean $f(x,y)=x+3$, then in this case it is understood that $x$ and $y$ are both elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, and that the input is $(x,y)$, an element of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. In this case, $f(x,y)=x+3$ is well-defined, even though the function assignment doesn't use the variable $y$. (Think about a constant function $f(x)=3$, for example - it doesn't use the variable $x$, but is still well-defined.)